# is there a tool that will detect a recursive function call in C code?

Tags: c, recursion

I need to search and eliminate recursive function calls in an inherited  code base.
Thus far I was unable to find any tool  that will do a static analysis and find these functions.

Comment: @sth: why do you want to know?

Comment: @duedl0r: Because whatever problem he is trying to solve might have a better solution than avoiding recursive functions

Comment: Its non negotiable.  The  client insists  that there will be zero recursion in the  code.   I tried everything but the Confundus Charm to no avail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to try [cflow](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/cflow.html):

> The cflow utility shall analyze a collection of object files or assembler, C-language, lex, or yacc source files, and attempt to build a graph, written to standard output, charting the external references.

It should print a callgraph and mark the recursive functions.

Comment: cflow did the job quite nicely (with a little bit of help from a ruby scrip I wrote), I preferred a static analyzer solution over having to run the software as I don't wish to dive in deep to find the maxmimal coverage scenarios.  it appear however, that GNU  cflow will only compile from linux based system.  anybody knows of  a windows port ?

Answer (score 4):

If your code has indirect calls thru function pointers, detecting recursive calls in it could be extremely difficult (and probably impossible in the general case, since equivalent to the halting problem.).

But I am not sure at all that eliminating recursion is worth the effort.  For some recursive algorithms or problems, you'll just replace it by simulating it with a stack (in heap), and that don't help much (and makes the code unreadable).

A more pragmatic solution (at least on Linux) would be to limit the stack size, and run tests till they break by filling the stack. Then you can use the debugger to understand how it happens.

I think you should not bother that much about recursion...

Comment: Never thought about the idea of limiting the stack size/causing a stackoverflow. Great suggestion!

Comment: Another way to sample the running program would be to compile it with profiling enabled (-pg in gcc), and then run (g)prof on the results. Gprof displays (rudimentary) callgraphs.

Answer (score 0):

[CIL](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~necula/cil/) can produce a CFG for C programs, but it is a bit like using a sledgehammer to put in a staple.